# How to swap the semicolon and colon keys in Normal-mode mappings in Vim?

Tags: vim

In an attempt to make myself use the shorter keystroke to get a colon, I have the following mappings defined in my `.vimrc` file:

```
noremap ; :
noremap : ;
```

However, this breakes some of my other mappings, since now it interprets a colon as a semicolon. For example, the mapping

```
map ,c :cd ~/code<CR>
```

becomes

```
map ,c ;cd ~/code<CR>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you need to remap colon? I just use `nnoremap ; :` and that's it.

Comment: @alberge:  Using only the first one of those mappings, you shadow the `;` Normal mode command.  When the second mapping is added, the meanings of `;` and `:` are swapped.

Comment: Wow, how did I never think of using this mapping? I'm going to go add it to my .vimrc right now.

Comment: Similar thought occured to me just now as well, decided to globally swap them since I use colon much more often :) https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/615799/swap-semicolon-colon-to-p-unexpected-cause-semicolon-colon-affected-by-cpas-lock

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The commands of the `:map` family interpret the characters in the
mapping definition as if they were typed by the user, so that any of
the currently defined mappings (including the one being defined) are
triggered as usual. It is the reason why it becomes possible to define
recursive or nested mappings when necessary. And this is also why the
colon mapping gets applied to other mappings defined via `:map`, like
the one in your example:

```
:map ,c :cd ~/code<cr>
```

To avoid this behavior, use the `:noremap` family of commands, which
do not interpret any mappings in the right-hand side of a mapping
definition (see `:help :nore`):

```
:noremap ,c :cd ~/code<cr>
```

In most cases, such interference with other mappings is an undesirable
side effect. As a rule of thumb, I would recommend one to go by the
following convention when defining a new mapping:

> Always use the `:noremap` family of commands,
> unless there is a clear reason not to.